# Number sequence with a clue

Tags: number-sequence

Spiderman's aunt walked back home

25,18,18,16,1,14,21,19,n

What's the value of n? Please let me know if the cryptic clue helped and any suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: All of these numbers are less than 26. Hmm..

Comment: Yeah, but YRRPANUS_ doesn't seem very word-like :-).

Comment: I'm wondering if these are issue numbers.

Comment: could you please check your puzzLe again if this is correct or not?

Comment: @Kingrames - I thought something similar... but I don't have the means to check. I also considered the fact that the aunts name is "May" so it could have something to do with months... but had no luck down that front either.

Comment: If it was months n= 4 or n=17 but I don't see any logic to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hint refers to

> The months (Aunt May), and traversing letters backwards from the end ("walked back")

So,

> For the $n^{th}$ month, take the value of the $n^{th}$ last letter. For $l$ = length of month name, wrap around (or take $n := n-l$) if $n > l$. 
> January, 1st last letter = Y = **25** 
> February, 2nd last letter = R = **18** 
> March, 3rd last letter = R = **18** 
> April, 4th last letter = P = **16** 
> May, 5th last letter = (5-3) 2nd last letter = A = **1** 
> June, 6th last letter = (6-4) 2nd last letter = N = **14** 
> July, 7th last letter = (7-4) 3rd last letter = U = **21** 
> August, 8th last letter = (8-6) 2nd last letter = S = **19**

So the solution is

> September, 9th last letter = S = **19**

Comment: correct on all counts :)